# Fastlane is unable to create the new app on apple developer portal

Tags: ios, react-native, release, fastlane

### Fastlane env:

```
<details><summary> fastlane environment </summary>

### Stack

| Key                         | Value                                       |
| --------------------------- | ------------------------------------------- |
| OS                          | 10.14.6                                     |
| Ruby                        | 2.5.8                                       |
| Bundler?                    | false                                       |
| Git                         | git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)        |
| Installation Source         | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin/fastlane |
| Host                        | Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G5033)                  |
| Ruby Lib Dir                | /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.5/2.5.8/lib        |
| OpenSSL Version             | OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020                 |
| Is contained                | false                                       |
| Is homebrew                 | false                                       |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false                                       |
| Xcode Path                  | /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ |
| Xcode Version               | 11.3.1                                      |


### System Locale

| Error                       |
| --------------------------- |
| No Locale with UTF8 found  |


### fastlane files:

**No Fastfile found**


**No Appfile found**


### fastlane gems

| Gem      | Version | Update-Status |
| -------- | ------- | ------------- |
| fastlane | 2.150.1 | ✅ Up-To-Date  |


### Loaded fastlane plugins:

**No plugins Loaded**


<details><summary><b>Loaded gems</b></summary>

| Gem                       | Version      |
| ------------------------- | ------------ |
| did_you_mean              | 1.2.0        |
| slack-notifier            | 2.3.2        |
| atomos                    | 0.1.3        |
| CFPropertyList            | 3.0.2        |
| claide                    | 1.0.3        |
| colored2                  | 3.1.2        |
| nanaimo                   | 0.2.6        |
| xcodeproj                 | 1.17.0       |
| rouge                     | 2.0.7        |
| xcpretty                  | 0.3.0        |
| terminal-notifier         | 2.0.0        |
| unicode-display_width     | 1.7.0        |
| terminal-table            | 1.8.0        |
| plist                     | 3.5.0        |
| public_suffix             | 4.0.5        |
| addressable               | 2.7.0        |
| multipart-post            | 2.0.0        |
| word_wrap                 | 1.0.0        |
| tty-screen                | 0.8.0        |
| tty-cursor                | 0.7.1        |
| tty-spinner               | 0.9.3        |
| babosa                    | 1.0.3        |
| colored                   | 1.2          |
| highline                  | 1.7.10       |
| commander-fastlane        | 4.4.6        |
| excon                     | 0.75.0       |
| faraday                   | 1.0.1        |
| unf_ext                   | 0.0.7.7      |
| unf                       | 0.1.4        |
| domain_name               | 0.5.20190701 |
| http-cookie               | 1.0.3        |
| faraday-cookie_jar        | 0.0.6        |
| faraday_middleware        | 1.0.0        |
| fastimage                 | 2.1.7        |
| gh_inspector              | 1.1.3        |
| json                      | 2.3.1        |
| mini_magick               | 4.10.1       |
| multi_xml                 | 0.6.0        |
| rubyzip                   | 2.3.0        |
| security                  | 0.1.3        |
| xcpretty-travis-formatter | 1.0.0        |
| dotenv                    | 2.7.5        |
| bundler                   | 2.1.4        |
| naturally                 | 2.2.0        |
| simctl                    | 1.6.8        |
| jwt                       | 2.1.0        |
| uber                      | 0.1.0        |
| declarative               | 0.0.20       |
| declarative-option        | 0.1.0        |
| representable             | 3.0.4        |
| retriable                 | 3.1.2        |
| mini_mime                 | 1.0.2        |
| multi_json                | 1.14.1       |
| signet                    | 0.14.0       |
| memoist                   | 0.16.2       |
| os                        | 1.1.0        |
| googleauth                | 0.13.0       |
| httpclient                | 2.8.3        |
| google-api-client         | 0.38.0       |
| google-cloud-env          | 1.3.2        |
| google-cloud-errors       | 1.0.1        |
| google-cloud-core         | 1.5.0        |
| digest-crc                | 0.6.0        |
| google-cloud-storage      | 1.26.2       |
| emoji_regex               | 3.0.0        |
| jmespath                  | 1.4.0        |
| aws-partitions            | 1.337.0      |
| aws-eventstream           | 1.1.0        |
| aws-sigv4                 | 1.2.1        |
| aws-sdk-core              | 3.103.0      |
| aws-sdk-kms               | 1.35.0       |
| aws-sdk-s3                | 1.72.0       |
</details>


*generated on:* **2020-07-03**
</details>
```

I am unable to create a new app and Fastlane doesn't even specify why I am unable to create it. I am just shown a message that something went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Fastlane stuck at app creation]

**EDIT**
Seems to be an existing issue

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15252

Comment: Just ran into this issue. Have you been able to fix it in the meantime?

Comment: Created the app on the developer portal after buying the dev subscription

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I solved my problem. I was using an `_` in the app identifier which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems like it was due to the name of app which already existed.  It worked after changing the name.